# Have two SQLite databases reference eachother

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm very new to SQL. I've read through a bunch of questions on how to join or attach two different SQLite databases together but I haven't founds success using any of the methods described. The problem is likely rooted in my own misunderstanding of how SQL works but here goes:

I'd like to create two different SQL databases, one for users of a site, and one for messages sent between users.

The schema for the `users` db (filename: blog_users.sqlite) looks like this:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS user;

CREATE TABLE user (
 id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
 username TEXT UNIQUE NOT NULL,
 password TEXT NOT NULL
);
```

The schema I came up with for the `messages` db looks like this:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS user;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS message;

ATTACH DATABASE 'blog_users.sqlite' AS 'users';

CREATE TABLE user (
 id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
 username TEXT UNIQUE NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE message (
 id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
 author_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
 created TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 title TEXT NOT NULL,
 body TEXT NOT NULL,
 FOREIGN KEY (author_id) REFERENCES users.user (id)
);
```

The ability to create a message should be constrained by requiring a user id which should be pulled from the `users` db, which is why I tried to use `FOREIGN KEY`.

Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong, or point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell, SQLite's foreign key constraints can't be created between tables that belong to different databases.

Though, as of your data model: do you *really* need to use two databases? Why can't USER table, that belongs to the MESSAGES database, be used as the *only* USER table? If nothing else, you'd be able to create that foreign key constraint ...

Comment: I've never really designed databases before, so I wasn't sure if that was best practice or not.